# How to remove silicone from brick

Tags: wood, windows, cleaning, brick, silicone

I had my windows replaced earlier this week. The old windows had metal U brackets to guide the rolling shutters. The gap between them and the brick wall was closed using some kind of (grey) silicone.

Now with the new wooden windows in place (without those U brackets), I noticed there are still remnants of the old silicone on the brick and this bugs me a lot. I tried scraping it off (very carefully) using a knife. This works for the thick pieces, but it leaves behind a grey color on the brick.

Is there a way to remove the color left by the silicone on the brick completely?

The windows have an oil based coating. I don't want to risk damaging this coating (or the wood), so I hope this is somehow possible.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's going to be tough: http://homeguides.sfgate.com/removing-silicone-caulk-residue-28359.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that complete removal is an option.  As a result, the way I would tackle this is as follows:

First, remove as much as possible with scraping.

Next, paint (matching the brick color).

If that still doesn't provide an acceptable asthetic, cover it up.  Contact the window manufacturer to find out what stain was used and make a trim piece of wood that will cover the gap and the residual caulk.

Comment: Good idea about the paint. The bricks arent uniformly colored though. I'm going to check with my local paint supplier if they offer some small 'tubes' of paint that I can mix and match at home. The trim is also a good option, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Silicone is soluble in vinegar.  Try applying some vinegar to the remaining residue with a sponge, waiting 30 minutes or so, then trying to rub it off (perhaps with a stiff brush).

Comment: Cured exterior grade silicone caulking is absolutely not soluble in vinegar.